# Como listar em árvore arquivos e sub-diretórios no Delphi?

Tags: delphi, lazarus, object-pascal

Criei um projeto em Pascal-Object e em um dado momento ele deve listar todos os arquivos e subdiretórios situados no Desktop em árvore, encontrei alguns exemplos na WEB, mas nenhum foi útil o bastante, pois só listava diretórios superficiais e os sub-sequentes ficavam sem ser listados.

Um exemplo bem claro de como deve ser é o da imagem abaixo:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você está desenvolvendo uma aplicação console? Precisa disso desenhado ou em forma de texto?

Comment: Não, na verdade esta imagem foi apenas para dar exemplo, na verdade a aplicação é VLC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você não especificou em que tipo de componente deve ser exibido, no exemplo abaixo é feito isso usando um TTreeView. Você vai precisar de um TTreeView e um button no form.

Fonte: http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=400

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ComCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    TreeView1: TTreeView;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure GetDirectories(Tree: TTreeView; Directory: string; Item: TTreeNode;
      IncludeFiles: Boolean);
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Node: TTreeNode;
  Path: string;
  Dir: string;
begin
  Dir := 'c:\temp\';
  Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
  TreeView1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    TreeView1.Items.Clear;
    GetDirectories(TreeView1, Dir, nil, True);
  finally
    Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
    TreeView1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.GetDirectories(Tree: TTreeView; Directory: string; Item: TTreeNode; IncludeFiles: Boolean);
var
  SearchRec: TSearchRec;
  ItemTemp: TTreeNode;
begin
  Tree.Items.BeginUpdate;
  if Directory[Length(Directory)] <> '\' then Directory := Directory + '\';
  if FindFirst(Directory + '*.*', faDirectory, SearchRec) = 0 then
  begin
    repeat
      if (SearchRec.Attr and faDirectory = faDirectory) and (SearchRec.Name[1] <> '.') then
      begin
        if (SearchRec.Attr and faDirectory > 0) then
          Item := Tree.Items.AddChild(Item, SearchRec.Name);
        ItemTemp := Item.Parent;
        GetDirectories(Tree, Directory + SearchRec.Name, Item, IncludeFiles);
        Item := ItemTemp;
      end
      else if IncludeFiles then
        if SearchRec.Name[1] <> '.' then
          Tree.Items.AddChild(Item, SearchRec.Name);
    until FindNext(SearchRec) <> 0;
    FindClose(SearchRec);
  end;
  Tree.Items.EndUpdate;
end;
end.
```

Mas existem outros componentes que podem ser usados nesse sentido.

Comment: Parabéns, melhor resposta, consegui salvar os dados em um arquivo de texto da mesma forma que um TMemo.

Answer (score 1):

Tenho um procedimento que acredito resolver seu problema:

```
procedure frmTeste.BuscaSubDiretorios(strNomeDir: String; Pai: TTreeNode);
var
  sr: TSearchRec;
  FileAttrs: Integer;
  strNome: String;
begin
  FileAttrs := faDirectory;
  strNome := strNomeDir;
  while strNome[Length(strNome)] = '\' do
    strNome := copy(strNome,1,length(strNome) - 1);
  if strNome[Length(strNome)] <> ':' then
    strNome := ExtractFileName(strNome)
  else
    strNome := copy(strNome,1,length(strNome) - 1);
  Pai := TreeView1.Items.AddChild(Pai,strNome);

  if FindFirst(strNomeDir + '*.*', FileAttrs, sr) = 0 then
  begin
    begin
      repeat
        //verifica se o arquivo encontrado é uma pasta
        if (sr.Name <> '.') and (sr.Name <> '..') and
           ((sr.Attr > 15) and (sr.Attr < 32)) then 
        begin
          BuscaSubDiretorios(strNomeDir + sr.Name + '\',Pai);
        end;
      until FindNext(sr) <> 0;
      FindClose(sr);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Para chamar o procedimento você usa: `BuscaSubDiretorios('c:\temp\',TreeView1.Selected);`

Observe que estamos usando um `TreeView` (componente da aba Win32)

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure TForm1.Listar(const Strings: TStrings; const strDiretorio: string; strPrefixo: string);
var
   sr: TSearchRec;
begin
   if FindFirst(strDiretorio + '\*', faDirectory, sr) = 0 then
      try
         Strings.BeginUpdate;
         try
            repeat
               if (sr.Name <> '.') and (sr.Name <> '..') then
               begin
                  if sr.Attr = faDirectory then
                  begin
                     Strings.Add(strPrefixo + strDiretorio + '\' + sr.Name);
                     Listar(Strings, strDiretorio + '\' + sr.Name, strPrefixo + #9);
                  end;

               end;
            until FindNext(sr) <> 0;
         finally
            Strings.EndUpdate;
         end;
      finally
         FindClose(sr);
      end;
end;
```

ai voce usa:

```
Listar(mmoSaida.Lines, 'D:\Diretorio');
```

aonde

```
mmoSaida: TMemo;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seu exemplo foi uma simples cópia de um outro que vi na internet anteriormente e como eu disse, não lista sub-diretórios em árvore, ainda cheguei a por uma imagem na pegunta para auxiliar na compreensão do leitor. Além disso, seu exemplo faz referência de uma variável que não foi criada "Strings" (6ª linha). Perdoe-me se eu estiver errado, por isso, peço que deixe sua resposta mais clara e se possível que você faça um teste antes de responder/corrigir.

Comment: alterei o código ai, só você colocar o strPrefixo que você quiser.

Comment: Tentei de todas as formas possíveis, mas sempre há falhas, você poderia "upar" sua unity em uma nuvem e compartilhar o link aqui?